# date and time from oracle db

Tags: sql, oracle, date-formatting

in my oracle db date format is like "13.10.2015 22:25:56"
 but after doing this select in my site date format is changing like this "13-OCT-15" - without hh:mm:ss

```
    <table border='1' align='left' bordercolor='navy' width='13%'>
    <tr>
            <td align="center">date - number</td>
    </tr>


<td align="center">
<?php 
$Date_1 = $_POST['Date_1'];
$Date_2 = $_POST['Date_2'];


$conn = oci_connect('login', 'password', '(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=host)(PORT=port) (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=service)))');
if (!$conn) {
    $e = oci_error();
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$sql="SELECT DATE, NUMBER FROM DB.RESULT
WHERE (DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('{$Date_1} 00:00:00', 'YYYY.MM.DD HH24:MI:SS')
AND TO_DATE('{$Date_2} 23:59:59', 'YYYY.MM.DD HH24:MI:SS'))
ORDER BY DATE desc";
$stid = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
oci_execute($stid);
echo "<table border='1' align='left' width='100%' height='100%' bordercolor=navy>\n";
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {

    foreach ($row as $item) {
        echo "    <td align='center'>" . ($item !== null ? htmlentities($item, ENT_QUOTES) : "&nbsp;") . "</td>\n","</td>\n";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n"; 
echo "</td>";  ?>
```

Comment: If DATE column is date type, you should convert it using TO_CHAR. `TO_CHAR (DATE,'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> in my oracle db date format is like "13.10.2015 22:25:56" but after doing this select in my site date format is changing like this "13-OCT-15" - without hh:mm:ss

Oracle does not store dates in the format you see. It stores it internally in proprietary format in 7 bytes with each byte storing different components of the datetime value.

Use **TO_CHAR** along with **FORMAT MODEL** to display the datetime in your desired format.

For example,

```
SQL> SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') my_format FROM DUAL;

MY_FORMAT
-------------------
10/15/2015 14:19:47
```

Modify your code to:

```
$sql="SELECT TO_CHAR(DATE, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') as "DATE", NUMBER FROM DB.RESULT
WHERE (DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('{$Date_1} 00:00:00', 'YYYY.MM.DD HH24:MI:SS')
AND TO_DATE('{$Date_2} 23:59:59', 'YYYY.MM.DD HH24:MI:SS'))
ORDER BY DATE desc";
```